# how to upload my players profile pics in unity c# to imgur privately

Tags: c#, api, unity-game-engine, imgur

i am making a game in unity
it's quite challenging game to my normal skills
i've successfully done the registration code :D

but i am struggling at uploading players pics to server
i've already tried imgur and followed all steps at this github [repo](https://github.com/GamingAnonymous/Imgur-for-Unity)

but it seems like it's not uploading. then i did some debugging i found out that
it's uploading but anomalously that's why i didn't get info such as:(title, description, tags ... etc) back.

> here is what i've got so far >> [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16iC9YPHfL-IzFfSPMbtVf1AuJKytE61q) <<

and here what i think that is the buggy part

```
public void UploadImage(string base64Image){
    Upload(base64Image, (response) =>{
        if (OnImageUploaded != null){
            OnImageUploaded(this, new OnImageUploadedEventArgs(response));
            Debug.Log("uploading completed!");
        }else{
            Debug.Log("OnImageUploaded = null");
        }
    });
}


private void Upload(string base64Image, Action<ImgurUploadResponse> OnUploadCompleted){
    Thread t = new Thread(() =>{
        using (WebClient wclient = new WebClient()){
            wclient.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Client-ID " + _clientId);
            NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection(){
                { "image", base64Image }
            };

            byte[] response = wclient.UploadValues(_baseUploadUrl, parameters);
            string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);

            Debug.Log("completed "+json);                       // it's here this debug never called
            OnUploadCompleted(JsonUtility.FromJson<ImgurUploadResponse>(json));
        }
    })
    {IsBackground = true};

    t.Start();
    Debug.Log("uploading started!");
}
```

Comment: Unity doesn't have tasks? Did you check how many bytes you get after uploading? Seems weird that debug line doesn't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity works with coroutines, not with Tasks. 
You can change your script like so:

```
private IEnumerator Upload(string base64Image, Action<ImgurUploadResponse> OnUploadCompleted){
        using (WebClient wclient = new WebClient()){
            wclient.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Client-ID " + _clientId);
            NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection(){
                { "image", base64Image }
            };

            byte[] response = wclient.UploadValues(_baseUploadUrl, parameters);
            string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);

            Debug.Log("completed "+json);
            OnUploadCompleted(JsonUtility.FromJson<ImgurUploadResponse>(json));
        }
}
```

And call it using StartCoroutine

```
public void UploadImage(string base64Image){
    StartCoroutine(
    Upload(base64Image, (response) =>{
        if (OnImageUploaded != null){
            OnImageUploaded(this, new OnImageUploadedEventArgs(response));
            Debug.Log("uploading completed!");
        }else{
            Debug.Log("OnImageUploaded = null");
        }
    }));
}
```

If this does not work, then you might want to take a look at [WWWForm](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html)

Comment: what should i return from the IEnumerator Upload

Comment: Right, that's why it wont work in unity. Ienumerator does not return anything. You would have to write Yield return yourwebrequesthere; 
You would get the return value in the callback. I'd suggest looking at the link i posted

Comment: Misleading answer. Coroutine is not a Thread. WebClient should be used in a Thread like OP did not with a coroutine.

Comment: okay, enough trying i followed your link it did help. but here is what i got 
remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

do you know another easier server and more secure cause you know these images i wanna upload are my client's profile images so?